# Text in div converted to comment

Tags: javascript, php, html

I'd like to "send" php from div, line this:

```
<div id='php'><?$login="login"; $password="password";?></div>
```

where "login" and "password" is variable.

but when i try to do it

```
document.getElementById('php').innerHTML = "<?$login=" + login + ";$password=" + password + ";?>"
```

But this text coming as comment `<!--<?$login=login;$password=password;?>-->` and it's happened EVERY time, when i try to add `<? echo(\"text\"); ?>` it's not work too.

How i can manage php from js & element.innerHTML with div?

Comment: `<?$login` no space in there is an issue `<? $login` and make sure short tags are enabled. Otherwise `<?php $login` same for the other one. You also need to echo it.

Comment: No. I try to do it, but it doesn't work.

`innerHTML = "<?php echo(\"Something\"); ?>"`

Comment: What is the output within `div#php`?

Comment: `<div><!--?php echo("Something"); ?--></div>`

Comment: you sure you're running this under a php environment and as `http://localhost` and not `file:///`?

Comment: I use hostinger. Look on it => http://cat-land.esy.es/game.php

Comment: You can't use PHP in a js file.

Comment: No. when i add to html page `<div><? $login = "login"?></div>` (without js, in html) it's work. with innerHTML it's not work and converted to comment..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use PHP values in a javascript document. Instead, assign them globally in your PHP document that your js file can use:

In your game.php:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
   var login = "<?php echo $login; ?>";
   var password = "<?php echo $password; ?>";
</script>
```

Then you can use those values in your javascript file:

```
function Start()
{
    php.innerHTML = 'login:'+login+'password:'+password;
}
```

Tweak your innerHTML string as needed.

Comment: It's not work too.

`var log_Enter = "<?php echo(\"login\")?>";
php.innerHTML = log_Enter;`


And i've got `<div id='php'> <!--?php echo("login")?--></div>`

Comment: Where did you place the `var log_Enter`? You're probably messing things up by escaping the quotes. You do not need to do that when echoing from PHP. Escaping quotes only need to be done inside the string.

Comment: i try `function Start()
{
   var log_Enter = "<?php echo(\"login\")?>";
   php.innerHTML = log_Enter;
}` 

and `var log_Enter = "<?php echo(\"login\")?>"; function Start()
{
   php.innerHTML = log_Enter;

}` and `<script>var log_Enter</script>`

Comment: Again, you can't put PHP inside a javascript file. And take the double quotes out of your echoes.

Comment: so you think
`
var login = "<?php echo $login; ?>";
   var password = "<?php echo $password; ?>";

function Start 
{
php.innerHTML = login 
}`
work?

Comment: Assigning the variables MUST be done in your PHP page. But yes, it should. Make sure you've assigned the values to `$login` and `$password` before you try to echo them.

Comment: Okey, i try it now

Comment: `$login` and `$password` has been created but `var login = '<?php echo($login); ?>'

function Start()
{
   php.innerHTML = login;

} `
isn't working

Comment: If what you've tried is what's on the live site, I will say it again. PHP CANNOT GO IN YOUR JS FILE.

Comment: but what is it ._.

`<script type="text/javascript">
   var login = "<?php echo $login; ?>";
   var password = "<?php echo $password; ?>";
</script>`

if php cannot go in js file you do it. or you try say me about creating new <script></script>?

Comment: oh.. i understand. now i retry, sorry

Comment: Javascript can go into a PHP file. The script tags are how you can place javascript inline in your html/php file. If the file is named PHP, it will run through the PHP processor on the server. Files named .js will not run through the PHP processor. Anything not enclosed in the PHP tags, including javascript, will be ignored by the processor.